# Exact match document in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I am currently using MongoDB's driver on a Java application. Suppose I have the two following documents stored in a collection:

Document A:

```
{
  "_id": "something",
  "key1": "Value1",
  "Key2": "Value2",
  "Key3": "Value3"
}
```

Document B:

```
{
  "_id": "somethingDifferent",
  "key1": "Value1",
  "Key2": "Value2"
}
```

Now, I want to retrieve an exact match of DocumentB's from the collection without also returning Document A, by using key1 and key2's values, and not _id since I don't know it beforehand.

If I just use DocumentB as a query (without _id), Mongo will also return DocumentA since it has matches all the keys and values, disconsidering the fact that DocumentA has an extra key (key3).

Is there any way to perform this "exact match" query in Mongo? Will I have to implement a check afterwards?

Comment: You can use `_id` (if you know its value) to get an exact match for any document. Does document  B has a field called as ""key3?

Comment: I don't know _id beforehand. I want to query for key1 and 2 only.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by "exact match" you mean the document has no other fields but the ones in the query.

You will need to use aggregation framework to retrieve a list of keys in the object and filter out the ones that have unexpected keys.
In mongodb syntax it can be like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
        "key1": "Value1",
        "Key2": "Value2"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      extra_keys: {
        $setDifference: [
          {
            $map: {
              input: {
                $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
              },
              in: "$$this.k"
            }
          },
          [                   // <== the list of keys in the query
            "_id",
            "key1",
            "Key2"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      extra_keys: []
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Do I really need everything in this JSON? I am not very experienced in Mongo, but it seems to me there is a lot there that is not useful (like the last $match object) in this case.

Comment: The last $match is the one that filters out the documents with extra fields.

Comment: Do you have any idea of how that is performed with Java? There you wrote down the JSON for it. In Java we use objects for querying. If not, I will look for the aggregation framework in Java myself. Thank you for the answer. I will test it first before flagging it as correct.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know Java good enough to provide an answer. https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/builders/aggregation/ should give some ideas about pipeline stages, and the functions should be simple Documents, e.g. `new Document("$setDifference", Arrays.asList(...))`, `new Document("$map", ....)` etc

Answer (score 1):

If your matching query `key:value` pair has the same order than your stored documents, the aggregation below [may work with **$eq** operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#objects).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            "key1": "Value1",
            "Key2": "Value2"
          },
          {
            $arrayToObject: {
              $filter: {
                input: {
                  $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
                },
                cond: {
                  $ne: [
                    "$$this.k",
                    "_id"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pLUvRwMBMC6)

**Warning:** These objects are equals

```
{                          {
  "key1": "Value1"   ----      "key1": "Value1",
  "Key2": "Value2",  ----      "Key2": "Value2"
}                          }
```

These objects are **not** equals

```
{                          {
  "key1": "Value1"   --/-      "Key2": "Value2",
  "Key2": "Value2",  -/--      "key1": "Value1"
}                          }
```